# Python regex negative lookbehind including start of line

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, negative-lookbehind

consider the following input:

```
"aaa"|"bbb"|"123"|"!"\\"|"2010-01-04T00:00:01"
```

I am trying to write a regex that will capture and replace the double quote character with tilde if...

- it is not preceded or followed by the delimiter `|` AND
- it is not at the start of the line AND
- it is not at the end of the line

In PHP I am able to get the regex pictured below working...
[image: php_regex]

Due to constraints on the python regex, the same regex fails with the following error:

```
re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

my python code is as follows:

```py
import re
orig_line = r'"aaa"|"bbb"|"123"|"!"\\"|"2010-01-04T00:00:01"'
new_line = re.sub(pattern='(?<!\||^)\"(?!\||$)',repl='~',string=orig_line)
```

How can I adjust this regex so it works in python?

Similar questions exist on SO, but I couldn't find any that address the start/end of line requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?<=[^|])
```

The `(?<=[^|])` matches a location that is immediately preceded with any char but `|` and thus it cannot match at the start of the string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/WNi9zy):

```
import re
orig_line = '"aaa"|"bbb"|"123"|"!"\\"|"2010-01-04T00:00:01"'
new_line = re.sub(r'(?<=[^|])"(?=[^|])', '~', orig_line)
print(new_line) # => "aaa"|"bbb"|"123"|"!~\"|"2010-01-04T00:00:01"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it following way: as you are interested in " which is not at start we can express it as *having one non-newline before* i.e. using positive lookbehind that is:

```
import re
orig_line = r'"aaa"|"bbb"|"123"|"!"\\"|"2010-01-04T00:00:01"'
new_line = re.sub(pattern='(?<=.)(?<!\|)\"(?!\||$)',repl='~',string=orig_line)
print(new_line)
```

output:

```
"aaa"|"bbb"|"123"|"!~\\"|"2010-01-04T00:00:01"
```

If you are not limited to python standard library I suggest trying [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) which does support variable-length lookbehinds for example:

```
import regex as re
text = "a1aa2aaa3aaaa4"
print(re.findall('(?<=a{3,})[0-9]', text))
```

output:

```
['3', '4']
```